# Split multiple gz compressed files into even more files

Tags: bash

I have a directory full of gz files. I need to split them into smaller ones, e.g. 1M of size.

I do e.g. for one file:

```
$ split --bytes=1m one_unzipped_file prefix_
```

but how to achieve for many files?

Comment: You already tagged the question [bash]. Thus I assume you want to solve this with a bash shell script (and no with find or any other method).

Which leads me to: "What have you already tried"? E.g. [for loops](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_01.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop, cd to directory and run a for loop.

```
cd folder    
for i in *.gz; do split --bytes=1m $i "$i_"; done
```

This will split file.gz, file2.gz, ... into file.gz_aa,file.gz_ab,..., file2.gz_aa,file2.gz_ab,...

Comment: You should remove the backtick quotes around `*.gz`, shell expansion will work just fine, and this actually tries to execute a command named by the shell expansion.

Comment: edited, i had a version with ls before, but forgot to remove the ticks at edit

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing:

```
$ gunzip *.gz
$ tar -cf - someFilePrefix* | split --bytes=1m subDir/prefix
```